# Aggregate data frame by date

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

```
structure(list(ticker = c("WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", "WMT", 
"WMT"), filingdate = structure(c(18551, 18551, 18551, 18537, 
18536, 18534), class = "Date"), formtype = c("4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4"), issuername = c("WALMART INC", "WALMART INC", "WALMART INC", 
"WALMART INC", "WALMART INC", "WALMART INC"), ownername = c("LORE MARC E", 
"LORE MARC E", "LORE MARC E", "BIGGS M BRETT", "LORE MARC E", 
"WALTON ALICE L"), officertitle = c("Executive Vice President", 
"Executive Vice President", "Executive Vice President", "Executive Vice President", 
"Executive Vice President", NA), isdirector = c("N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "N"), isofficer = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N"), 
    istenpercentowner = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y"), transactiondate = structure(c(18549, 
    18549, 18549, 18536, 18534, 18534), class = "Date"), securityadcode = c("ND", 
    "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND"), transactioncode = c("S", "S", 
    "S", "F", "F", "S"), sharesownedbeforetransaction = c(1669368, 
    1610399, 1591019, 302554, 1707160, 389404553), transactionshares = c(-58969, 
    -19380, -6651, -657, -37792, -606875), sharesownedfollowingtransaction = c(1610399, 
    1591019, 1584368, 301897, 1669368, 388797678), transactionpricepershare = c(144.114, 
    145.409, 145.891, 139.91, 137.25, 137.049), transactionvalue = c(8498258, 
    2818026, 970321, 91921, 5186952, 83171612), securitytitle = c("Common", 
    "Common", "Common", "Common Stock", "Common", "Common Stock"
    ), directorindirect = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "I"), natureofownership = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "By Trust"), dateexercisable = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), 
    priceexercisable = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), expirationdate = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), 
    rownum = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2), mycolumn = c(-8498258, -2818026, 
    -970321, -91921, -5186952, -83171612)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to compress my dataframe to sum all the values ​​in the "my column" column for each day of the "filingdate" column.
For example, the day 2020-10-16 is repeated 3 times. I would like the new data.frame to have a single row with the date 2020-10-16 and the "my column" column is the sum of its 3 values.
All the other columns can be deleted or they can keep the value of the last day.

The same goes for all other dates

Answer (score 0):

One option can be `aggregate()`:

```
#Code 1
newdf <- aggregate(mycolumn~filingdate,data=df,sum,na.rm=T)
```

Output:

```
  filingdate  mycolumn
1 2020-09-29 -83171612
2 2020-10-01  -5186952
3 2020-10-02    -91921
4 2020-10-16 -12286605
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code 2
newdf <- df %>% group_by(filingdate) %>% summarise(mycolumn=sum(mycolumn,na.rm=T))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  filingdate  mycolumn
  <date>         <dbl>
1 2020-09-29 -83171612
2 2020-10-01  -5186952
3 2020-10-02    -91921
4 2020-10-16 -12286605
```